# Do I need to enable Public Access when only 1 IAM user can access S3 Bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, laravel-5, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

**This is the set-up I want to have:**

- I want to use Amazon S3 bucket to store all photos uploaded by users
  in my App.
- None of these photos should be accessed by public. These are all
  secured photos and only authorised users can view them and no users
  will ever be able to access them directly from S3 bucket.
- Each time a user wants to view a photo, their GET request will reach
  my server's api route, which will do the authorisation check, and if
  they have permission, my server will contact S3 bucket, fetch the
  image and then my server returns this image back to the user.

Basically, my app users will never reach the S3 bucket directly, only my server is authorised to reach S3 bucket to GET, PUT and DELETE and no one else should be able to see anything in my S3 bucket.

**This is what I have done so far:**

1. Created IAM User with `"AmazonS3FullAccess"` policy.
2. Disabled all public access in my S3 bucket.
3. Created the following bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::myapp"
            ],
            "Principal": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::myapp/*"
            ],
            "Principal": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

**What Happens?**

1. When I paste the above, I get the `Access Denied` error.
2. When I searched SO on this, the answers recommend that I should uncheck `"Block public access to buckets and objects granted through new public bucket policies"`
3. When I uncheck the above, Amazon console keeps showing warning that it is not safe to provide public access to my bucket.
4. Although I am able to save the above bucket policy after enabling public access, the warning about having public access shown in the console is worrisome.

So, I really don't want to allow public access at all in my bucket. I only want my Laravel application in my server that uses the IAM credentials to access and fetch the images and no one else should have access to this S3 bucket.

I have read many links on this but I am still confused here.

**My questions are:**

1. In my use case, Should I need to enable Public Access to my bucket if I only want to allow 1 IAM user to access the bucket listing programatically?
2. Do I even need to set Bucket Policy? Since I have already set a policy when I created the IAM user, isin't that enough?
3. If I need to add a Bucket Policy as well, do I leave the Principal as `*` or do I need to add the `User ARB` here?
4. Am I able to add the Bucket Policy without enabling Public access?
5. Am I safe to do it with the above steps or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this and this is what I found:

> In my use case, Should I need to enable Public Access to my bucket if I only want to allow 1 IAM user to access the bucket listing programatically?

No need to enable Public Access. I have disabled all public access in my Bucket by checking: `"Do not grant public read access.."`

> Do I even need to set Bucket Policy? Since I have already set a policy when I created the IAM user, isin't that enough?

No need to add Bucket Policy. Instead adding the Policy directly to the IAM user does it and it's enough.

> If I need to add a Bucket Policy as well, do I leave the Principal as * or do I need to add the User ARB here?

No need bucket policy. Instead link the policy to the IAM user.

> Am I able to add the Bucket Policy without enabling Public access?

Not needed since public access can be left disabled and IAM user can still access it directly programatically.

> Am I safe to do it with the above steps or am I missing something?

**This is what I did:**

1. Disabled public access in bucket.
2. Removed the bucket policy and left it empty.
3. Create a new policy in IAM user dashboard. Below are the steps:

**Create Policy:**

[image: Create Policy]

**Add Service, Actions and Resources:**

[image]

Add Policy name, description, Review and Create.

[image]

4. Edited the IAM user and instead of assigning this user to "AmazonS3FullAccess" which has too much permission, I assigned the above custom policy created.

Doing this worked and my app is able to access the bucket. I tested it using Tinker:

[image]